# What is the blue round ring near the field 'Last Activity Date' in the view?

Tags: standard-objects, list-view

I noticed this blue ring near the fields on the Account object:

- Last Activity Date
- Next Activity Date

What do they stand for?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those fields are what we call **Activity Metrics** fields, that is available if you have Einstein Activity Capture with paid features (Inbox, Sales Cloud Einstein or High Velocity Sales)

More info: [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.aac_activity_metrics.htm&type=5)